# как запустить действие при загрузке страницы / js

Tags: javascript

у меня есть event на клик, хотелось бы так же запустить эту функцию без нажатия при загружке страницы.

```
generate.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const length = lengthEl.value;
    const hasLower = lowercaseEl.checked;
    const hasUpper = uppercaseEl.checked;
    const hasNumber = numbersEl.checked;
    const hasSymbol = symbolsEl.checked;
    
    resultEl.value  = generatePassword(hasLower, hasUpper, hasNumber, hasSymbol, length);
});
```

как можно решить это ?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleClick)` и колбэк из клика в функцию handleClick вынести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При загрузке (готовности) DOM:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') generate.click();
});
```

При полной загрузке страницы:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') generate.click();
});
```

Конечно же, слушатель клика должен быть добавлен **до** того как возникнет ожидаемое событие.

---

Кстати, так как слушатели обычно добавляются при готовности DOM - можно сразу их и вызывать (если нужно не ждать полной загрузки страницы, а просто выполнить обработчик как можно раньше, для инициализации):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  /* .... */
  const onGenerateClick = () => {
    resultEl.value = generatePassword(
      lowercaseEl.checked,
      uppercaseEl.checked,
      numbersEl.checked,
      symbolsEl.checked,
      lengthEl.value
    );
  };
  generate.addEventListener('click', onGenerateClick);
  onGenerateClick();
});
```